# How can I find a Google Document I edited yesterday?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

A coworker gave me a link to a doc. I edited it. Now I can't find it in my "recent" list or in the "shared with me" list.

The doc wasn't shared with me. It was a link to a doc that anyone could edit, if they have the link.

Answer (score 2):

If the file was edited by you, it should be displayed in Shared with me and in the recent list. If it isn't there, maybe it was deleted by the owner.

Try

- to find the file using the link that you used to open it.
- look for the link in the browser history
- ...

**References**
[Find your files - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?hl=en)

Comment: It's not in either of those places.  But I agree with you, it should be there. What I ended up doing was going back to my browser history and finding the link there. But I don't think that's the best solution. To do that I had to go back to my computer. But there should be a way for me to do it from my mobile.

Comment: Please add more details to your question i.e. if the situation occurs in the app for Android or for iOS, and if this also occurs using a web browser if you are using then [new Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6021313?hl=en) or the old one, and any other detail that could help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It happens on all operating systems. When I click a link for a doc that's open to anyone, it doesn't show up in my recent list. Try it. I bet you'll see the same. Thanks for checking this out Rubén

Comment: In my recent list I have several files owned by someone else, shared with anyone and edited yesterday :)